# Using BASH and JQ I want to compare a json file against a bash array

Tags: json, linux, bash, scripting, jq

Example:

**BASH ARRAY**
FRUITS=("apple" "banana" "orange")

**fruit.json**

```json
{
  "fruit": [
    "apple",
    "orange",
    "pomegranate",
    "apricot",
    "mango"
  ]
}
```

What I need to do:

1. Compare Bash fruit array against fruit.json file and output if it matches all the elements.
2. If the fruit.json file is missing a fruit element from the bash array I have to display which one it is.
3. If the fruit.json file has any extra fruit elements that are not in the bash array I have to output it.

I managed to figure out the first two tasks but I am having trouble with the third. Any ideas on how to achieve the third using bash and jq?

Comment: Is `"APPLE"` equal to `"apple"`? How do you distinguish the outputs of #2 and #3? Can you provide the expected output for the sample data used in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This response addresses the task for which help is requested:

> If the fruit.json file has any extra fruit elements that are not in the bash array I have to output it.

The following will output the strings corresponding to those elements in .fruit that do not appear in the bash array, assuming the entries in both arrays are all the same typographical case:

```
comm -23 <(< fruit.json jq -r '.fruit | sort[]') <(printf '%s\n' "${FRUITS[@]}" | sort )
```

This uses the standard command-line utilities `comm`, `sort`, and `printf`.  A "pure jq" solution would also be straightforward except perhaps for the importing of the elements of the bash array into jq.

If the typographical case is inconsistent, you could use `ascii_downcase` on the jq end, and `tr A-Z a-z` for the bash array elements.

Comment: Thanks for your help. New to bash and jq. One more question. If the fruit.json file was changed to have a food array, fruit array and the actual fruits name as elements. Would I change the command after -r to  .food[].fruit.name. Also I made a mistake in my original question. All arrays are lowercase

Comment: Please give an example of the new fruit.json.  Also, it would be helpful if you used the standard JSON terminology when referring to JSON data (see e.g. json.org). You could probably answer your question once you've scanned the jq documentation (e.g. the tutorial).

Answer (score 2):

Use `comm` to compare two lists.

```
comm \
  <(jq < fruit.json -r '.fruit | sort | .[] | ascii_upcase ') \
  <(printf "%s\n" "${FRUITS[@]}" | sort)
```

will output a three-column list: elements only in `fruit.json`, elements only in `FRUITS`, and common elements. To supress a column, use the appropriate options to `comm`: `-23` will suppress the second and third column, giving you just the `fruit.json`-only elements. Similarly, `-13` will provide just the `FRUITS`-only elements.

Comment: The items in the JSON array are not sorted, so a "sort" is needed. See e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comm-command-in-linux-with-examples/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "pure jq" solution to Part 3 except that it uses `printf` to facilitate the importing of the bash array:

```
printf '%s\n' "${FRUITS[@]}" | 
  jq -nRr --argfile fruit <(json) '($fruit.fruit | map(ascii_upcase)) - [inputs] | .[]'
```

This assumes that the strings in FRUITS are already uppercased, but does not assume they are sorted.

Note also that the semantics of jq's `-` applied to arrays is quite different from the semantics of `comm`, notably w.r.t. the handling of duplicates.